# creating files with reserved names

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows doesn't allow you to give files reserved names, such as `con`. However, WSL doesn't place any such restriction.

Creating a file called `con` produces an error: 'The specified device name is invalid.' Creating one with

```
touch con
```

in WSL does not produce any error, but then deleting it from Windows Explorer produces an error: 'Invalid file handle.' However,

```
rm con
```

in WSL deletes it without issue.

What is going on here? Why does WSL create a file with a reserved name without errors?

Comment: I don't use WSL, but: `con` in Windows would correspond to `/dev/console` in Linux. I don't think there is something in the Windows kernel  to prevent a file of this name, but Windows Explorer and `cmd` seem to block this. The same applies to, say, Cygwin: The Cygwin tools too allow me to create a `con` file. How about filenames consisting of a letter and a colon, such as `K:`. Can you create this using WSL?

Comment: With regards to K:, yes you can create such file in i.e. WSL's directories, but you can't create such file in mount point /mnt/c (which is drvfs).

Comment: Why? Because the only things not allowed in Linux file names are slashes and nulls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows blocks these file names from using them completely.(if e.g. you accessed a directory `C:\CON\CON` in an old windows version, you got a bluescreen)

So, you cannot access/create/delete them with cmd or explorer(It does not matter in which drive).

Howewer, the Filesystem does not block it. Because of this linux(maybe because something runs in the Windows Kernel?) shell emulators like git bash or wsl (I did not test cygwin) can create/access/delete these files even in the bootable Windows Partition.